# How to show store language in topmenu in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to show default store language in topmenu of homepage. I already put 
`<block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>` in `page.xml` and I called `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>`
in header section. but it is not shown in header or anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the store language using  direct call of phtml.Please call the code at topmenu.

Here the code is below-

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/switch')->setTemplate('page/switch/languages.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this in your .phtml

```
<?php
    /**
     * @var Mage_Core_Model_Locale $_locale
     */
    $_locale = Mage::app()->getLocale();
    $_language = $_locale->getTranslation(
        $_locale->getLocale()->getLanguage(),
        'language',
        $_locale->getLocale()
    );
    echo $_language;
?>
```